# Error found when importing spark.implicits

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using spark 1.4.0

When I tried to import spark.implicits using this command:
`import spark.implicits._`, this error appear:

```
<console>:19: error: not found: value spark
   import spark.implicits._
          ^
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because SparkSession is avialable from Spark 2.0 and `spark` value is an object of type SparkSession in Spark REPL.

In Spark 1.4 use

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
```

Value `sqlContext` is automatically created in Spark REPL for Spark 1.x

Answer (score 2):

To make it complete, first you have to create a `sqlContext`

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("my app")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._
```